# Linux kernel module wireless interface bit rate

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to obtain the bit rate of a wireless interface in a kernel module?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the instantaneous bit rate?  Or the bit maximum bit rate (i.e. the capacity)?

Comment: How about using the standard `iwconfig` tools? Or do you need a programmatic solution?

Comment: The instantaneous bit rate, if not possible how do I get the maximum one? And yes, I do need a programmatic solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the instantaneous rate, you could read the interface statistics. Either get them from `/proc/...` (?), or I think you need some IOCTL to query those. Just read evey 100ms and count packets, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but I think that you may use iw_range struct defined in libiw library (note that it's licensed under GPL, so be carefull when you use it in commercial application). You can do it in following way:

```
#include<iwlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* dev = "wlan0";
  int skfd = iw_sockets_open();
  int has_range = 0;
  struct iw_range range;
  int i = 0;
  has_range = (iw_get_range_info(skfd, dev, &range) >= 0);

  printf("Available %d bitrates\n", range.num_bitrates);
  while(i < range.num_bitrates)
  {
    printf("Available bitrate: %d\n", range.bitrate[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need to do this in kernel space. I'll have a look at those structures and see if there's something similar in kernel space. Anyway, thanks for your help and time :)